# Is $(F,W)$ a vector subspace of $(K,V)$ if $F$ is a sub-field of $K$?

Tags: linear-algebra, abstract-algebra

The question is simple. Let $(K,V)$ be a vector space where $K$ is the scalar field and $V$ is the vector abelian group. Typically $(K,W)$ is a subspace of $(K,V)$ if $W \subseteq V$ and $W$ satisfies the following conditions,

> [image]

However, my question is, if $(F,W)$ is as subspace of $(K,V)$ when $F$ is a sub-field of $K$, and $W$ satisfies all above conditions except for that $K$ is replaced by $F$?

There is a concrete example for this. Is $(\Bbb R, \Bbb R^n)$ a subspace of $(\Bbb C, \Bbb C^n)$?

Thank you!

Comment: No, generally the convention is that subspaces are over the same field.

Comment: I don't see why you couldn't realize it this way. $\mathbb C^n$ can be thought of as a $2n$ dimensional vector space over $\mathbb R$, so why can't you just take as your realization, the span of those basis vectors corresponding to the real parts of the complex numbers?

Comment: @AlfredYerger I think the op means specifically including the latter as a $\Bbb C$-vector space. if one replaces $K$ by the original $F$ then it's trivially true, of course. :)

Comment: @AdamHughes Right, I think maybe it's not particularly clear then. When you state it as you have, it's also trivially false. So I guess it's rather obvious either way, but it's not clear which is meant.

Comment: Strictly speaking, subspaces must carry the same base field.